# multiply certain columns based on name R dplyr

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have a dataset of the below form

```r
Product   1/1/2020.x  1/1/2019.x  1/1/2018_x  1/1/2020.y  1/1/2019.y  1/1/2018.y
   1          10          11          10           1           1           1
   2          12          12           0           2           1           0
   3          20          10          12           2           1           2
   4          30           3           1           3           3           1
   5          21           3           1           1           3           1
```

I want to create a new dataset where each x and y pair of columns(same date prefix) are multiplied. I cannot do it manually as the no of columns are more than 100. The resultant dataframe should be of the form as below.

```
Product   1/1/2020     1/1/2019    1/1/2018      
   1          10          11          10          
   2          24          12           0           
   3          40          10          24            
   4          90           9           1            
   5          21           9           1
```

Comment: checkout `pivot_longer` from the `tidyr` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using **tidyverse**

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- read.table(text = "Product   1/1/2020.x  1/1/2019.x  1/1/2018.x  1/1/2020.y  1/1/2019.y  1/1/2018.y
   1          10          11          10           1           1           1
   2          12          12           0           2           1           0
   3          20          10          12           2           1           2
   4          30           3           1           3           3           1
   5          21           3           1           1           3           1", header = T)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Product, names_to = c("set", ".value"), names_pattern = "(.*)(.)") %>% 
  transmute(Product, set, z = x * y) %>% 
  pivot_wider(Product, names_from = set, values_from = z)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   Product X1.1.2020. X1.1.2019. X1.1.2018.
#>     <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>
#> 1       1         10         11         10
#> 2       2         24         12          0
#> 3       3         40         10         24
#> 4       4         90          9          1
#> 5       5         21          9          1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Could you please explain the pivot_longer part of the code.

Comment: My English is bad for a good explanation. Using `names_pattern = "(.*)(.)"` we divide, for example, 1/1/2020. x into two parts. The "1/1/2020." part goes to the "set" column, and the numeric value goes to the "x" column. Examples can be found in the `?pivot_longer`help.