# Conditional multiplying based on column name

Tags: r, dataframe, multiplication, calculated-columns

I already checked [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66027021/multiply-certain-columns-based-on-name-r-dplyr) but it doesn't fit my data structure.

**Input**

I have a data frame `Portfolio` containing company indentifiers `Indentifier`, portfolio weights `Weight`, `Date`s and in the rest of the columns return data at least for each of the `Indentifier`s:

```
# Portfolio

            Indentifier      Weight       Date AIR.PA SCHN.PA ASML.AS  TCH.PA ERICb.ST SASY.PA  RE.PA TELIA.ST NOKIA.HE DAIGn.DE ALSO.PA ...

1               AIR.PA  0.007671609 2003-04-30 0.2164 -0.0112  0.3008  0.2772   0.4247  0.1592 0.2780   0.2138   0.1975   0.1351  0.2908
2               SCHN.PA 0.004302912 2003-05-30 0.1420 -0.0482  0.0904  0.1135   0.0729  0.0168 0.0210   0.0640   0.0092  -0.0744  0.8791
3               SCHN.PA 0.004302912 2003-06-30 0.1317  0.0533 -0.0201 -0.0588   0.0683 -0.0402 0.2177   0.0782  -0.0627   0.1364 -0.1228
4               AIR.PA  0.007671609 2003-06-30 0.3311  0.1661  0.4075  0.0424   0.3646 -0.0176 0.0738   0.0155  -0.0502   0.0556  0.0333
5               AIR.PA  0.007671609 2003-07-31 0.0188  0.0302  0.2328  0.1836   0.0923  0.0220 0.1104  -0.0257   0.0954   0.0810 -0.2774
...
```

I want to multiply the `Indentifier`s' `Weight` for a `Date` with the return stored in the column with the same column name as the `Indentifier`.

**Example**

For row `1` with the `Indentifier` `AIR.PA`, with the `Date` `2003-04-30`, the calculation would be: `Weight` `0.007671609` `*` return data `0.2164` `=` `0.001660`.

Ideally the output in `Portfolio` for `AIR.PA`, `SCHN.PA`, and `ASML.AS` would be the following:

```
# Portfolio

        Date  AIR.PA           SCHN.PA     ASML.AS  ...
        
1 2003-04-30  0.001660              NA          NA
2 2003-05-30        NA       -0.000207          NA
3 2003-06-30  0.002540        0.000229          NA
4 2003-07-31  0.000144              NA          NA   
...
```

Thanks in advance for the help! Best regards, Thomas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be straight forward like so:

```r
dat %>%
    pivot_longer( cols=-c(Identifier,Weight,Date) ) %>%
    mutate( score = Weight * value ) %>%
    filter( Identifier == name ) %>%
    pivot_wider( names_from=name, values_from=score ) %>%
    select( -c(Identifier,Weight,value) )
```

Applied to your data:

```r
dat <- read.table(text=
"            Identifier      Weight       Date AIR.PA SCHN.PA ASML.AS  TCH.PA ERICb.ST SASY.PA  RE.PA TELIA.ST NOKIA.HE DAIGn.DE ALSO.PA
1               AIR.PA  0.007671609 2003-04-30 0.2164 -0.0112  0.3008  0.2772   0.4247  0.1592 0.2780   0.2138   0.1975   0.1351  0.2908
2               SCHN.PA 0.004302912 2003-05-30 0.1420 -0.0482  0.0904  0.1135   0.0729  0.0168 0.0210   0.0640   0.0092  -0.0744  0.8791
3               SCHN.PA 0.004302912 2003-06-30 0.1317  0.0533 -0.0201 -0.0588   0.0683 -0.0402 0.2177   0.0782  -0.0627   0.1364 -0.1228
4               AIR.PA  0.007671609 2003-06-30 0.3311  0.1661  0.4075  0.0424   0.3646 -0.0176 0.0738   0.0155  -0.0502   0.0556  0.0333
5               AIR.PA  0.007671609 2003-07-31 0.0188  0.0302  0.2328  0.1836   0.0923  0.0220 0.1104  -0.0257   0.0954   0.0810 -0.2774
", header=TRUE ) %>% mutate( Date = as.Date(Date) )

dat %>%
    pivot_longer( cols=-c(Identifier,Weight,Date) ) %>%
    mutate( score = Weight * value ) %>%
    filter( Identifier == name ) %>%
    pivot_wider( names_from=name, values_from=score ) %>%
    select( -c(Identifier,Weight,value) )
```

Produces:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  Date          AIR.PA   SCHN.PA
* <date>         <dbl>     <dbl>
1 2003-04-30  0.00166  NA       
2 2003-05-30 NA        -0.000207
3 2003-06-30 NA         0.000229
4 2003-06-30  0.00254  NA       
5 2003-07-31  0.000144 NA
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will get more familiar with `pivot_longer()` and  `pivot_wider()`.

Comment: Np! You will get used to them, but it will take time.